# Using the pipeline ingest in elasticsearch to rename an element

Tags: elasticsearch, rename, kibana

I am trying to rename an element in elasticsearch and i am running into an issue.

I tried to rename this element "list to lists" so i tried _source.list and it worked.

Ok, after that, i tried renaming _source.list.metaData to metaDatas, and i seem to be running into an issue. here is the code i am using, and here is also the mapping.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/pipeline_rename_xxx
{
  "description" : "rename xxx",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "rename": {
        "field": "_source.list.metaDatas",
        "target_field": "metaDatas"
      }
    }
  ]
}

{
  "tweet": {
    "mappings": {
      "document": {
        "properties": {
          "list": {
            "properties": {
              "metaData": {



 "reason": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field [_source.list.metaData] doesn't exist"


This is what i am expecting

{
  "tweet": {
    "mappings": {
      "document": {
        "properties": {
          "list": {
            "properties": {
              "metaDatas": {

I will appreciate any help. Thanks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "promoted"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_promoted"
  }
}

PUT _ingest/pipeline/pipeline_rename_xxx
{
  "description": "rename xxx",
  "processors": [
    {
      "foreach": {
        "field": "list",
        "processor": {
          "foreach": {
            "field": "_ingest._value.promoted.league",
            "processor": {
              "foreach": {
                "field": "_ingest._value.league",
                "processor": {
                  "rename": {
                    "field": "_ingest._value.division.position",
                    "target_field": "_ingest._value.division.positions"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```